# getting relevant entry in SQL using where select statements

Tags: sql, select

I have table "Project" with lot of Project IDs, Project Name, Status and Period. Every month some projects closed. In the Below table for project 2332 Status is Closed in 2102 and 2103, but I want only entry for Closed and that also for 2102.

```
ProjectID | Project Name| Status| Period|
--------------------------------------------
2332       |ABC7827      |Active| 2102|
--------------------------------------------
2332       |ABC7827      |Closed| 2102|
--------------------------------------------
2332       |ABC7827      |Closed| 2103|
--------------------------------------------
8872       |MMF8827      |Active| 2102|
--------------------------------------------
9922       |PER9982      |Closed| 2102|
--------------------------------------------
100292     |YYE009       |Closed| 2102|
------------------------------------------
```

I am using the below code just see what ProjectId was present in Last month but not present in current month. I am not getting ProjectID 2332 in the result as it is present in both 2102 and 2103.

I am expecting below result

```
ProjectID | Project Name| Status| Period|
--------------------------------------------
2332       |ABC7827      |Closed| 2102|
--------------------------------------------
9922       |PER9982      |Closed| 2102|
--------------------------------------------
100292     |YYE009       |Closed| 2102|
--------------------------------------------






select *
from Project
where Period = 2102
  and ProjectID not in (Select ProjectID from Project where period = 2103)
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: `select * from project where Status=Closed and period= 2102`

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.  Your statement:

> I am using the below code just see what ProjectId was present in Last month but not present in current month. I am not getting ProjectID 2332 in the result as it is present in both 2102 and 2103.

This is contradictory.  According to the first sentence, you do not want 2332 in the results . . . as explained in the second sentence.

If you do want it in the results, then just check for 2012 statuses:

```
select p.*
from Project p
where Period = 2102 and status = 'Closed';
```

At least based on your sample data, this should return what you want.